# Having unused 'mergedProps' parameter on 'connect' throws error on component rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm using Redux for my current Typescript React project and have a bit of a hard time to get into it. Connecting components works fine so far for me though.

```
interface OwnProps {
    ownProp?: boolean;
}

interface PropsFromState {
    stateProp: any;
}

interface PropsFromDispatch {
    dispatchProp: (...) => void;
}

type MyComponentProps = OwnProps & PropsFromState & PropsFromDispatch;

class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps> {...}

const mapStateToProps = ({ componentState }: IAppState, ownProps: OwnProps): PropsFromState => {
    return {
        stateProp: componentState.stateProp,
        ownProp: ownProps.ownProp,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any): PropsFromDispatch => {
    return {
        dispatchProp: (...) => dispatch(dispatchProp(...))
    };
};
export default connect<PropsFromState, PropsFromDispatch, OwnProps>(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponent);
```

Just recently though I tried to put a ref on a connected component, where I found out that I had to enable the `forwardRef` option. So I updated the connection call to

```
export default connect<PropsFromState, PropsFromDispatch, OwnProps>(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
    null,
    { forwardRef : true }
)(MyComponent);
```

But because I had to put the third parameter for `mergedProps` in between (which I thought could default to `null` without any issues), `tslint` now throws an error for me when I try to render the component, saying something like

```
<MyComponent ownProp ref={ref => this.comp = ref}/>

Type '{ ownProp: true; ref: (ref: Component<Pick<MyComponent, "ownProp" | "stateProp" | "dispatchProp"> & OwnProps, any, any>) => Component<...>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<Pick<MyComponentProps, "ownProp" | "stateProp" | "dispatchProp"> & OwnProps>': stateProp, dispatchProp - ts(2739)
```

Seems like the component now requires the other props where it shouldn't require them. Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: After a lot of googling, I ended up exporting both, connected and unconnected Components, connected for use of redux, and unconnected for using ref. Worked out for me, but still looking for some real answer.